# Why is it that while taking the inverse matrix a Wronskian pops up in this solution?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on an ordinary differential equation solution when I saw another way that could be used to solve using matrices such that
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{matrix}
y_1\left(x\right) && y_2\left(x\right) \\ y_1'\left(x\right) && y_2'\left(x\right)
\end{matrix}\right)\bigg(\begin{matrix}
v_1'\left(x\right) \\
v_2'\left(x\right)
\end{matrix}\bigg)&=\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ \frac{G\left(x\right)}{a}\end{matrix}\right)\tag{1} \\
\implies\int\left(\begin{matrix}v_1'\left(x\right) \\ v_2'\left(x\right)\end{matrix}\right) & =\int\frac{\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ \frac{G\left(x\right)}{a}\end{matrix}\right)}{\left(\begin{matrix}
y_1\left(x\right) && y_2\left(x\right) \\ y_1'\left(x\right) && y_2'\left(x\right)
\end{matrix}\right)}\:dx\tag{2}
\end{align*}
But now, I've seen that (2) is re-written as
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\begin{matrix}0 \\ \frac{G\left(x\right)}{a}\end{matrix}\right)}{\left(\begin{matrix}
y_1\left(x\right) && y_2\left(x\right) \\ y_1'\left(x\right) && y_2'\left(x\right)
\end{matrix}\right)}&=\frac{1}{W\left[y_1,y_2\right]\left(x\right)}\left(\begin{matrix}
y_1\left(x\right) && y_2\left(x\right) \\ y_1'\left(x\right) && y_2'\left(x\right)
\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}\tag{3}\\ &=\frac{1}{W\left[y_1,y_2\right]\left(x\right)}\left(\begin{matrix}
y_2'\left(x\right) && -y_2\left(x\right) \\ -y_1'\left(x\right) && y_1\left(x\right)
\end{matrix}\right)\tag{4}\end{align}
So my question is, why is the left-hand side of (3) the same as (4)? I have not taken linear algebra as of yet, but it seems the inverse of the matrix is taken because its inverse on top is the same as it regularly stands in the denominator.

I understood the rest of the problem, it's just this step that I couldn't understand. It seems like introducing a Wronskian, just to ensure that the solutions are linearly independent, is like adding an extra term. But it definitely adds up to give the same results (somehow) since I still end up with
\begin{align}
v_1\left(x\right) & = -\int\frac{y_2\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)\:dx}{aW\left[y_1,y_2\right]\left(x\right)},\tag{5} \\ v_2\left(x\right) & =\int\frac{y_1\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)\:dx}{aW\left[y_1,y_2\right]\left(x\right)},\tag{6}
\end{align}
such that $f\left(x\right)$ is the *forcing term* on the RHS of the original ODE.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: [Inverse of $2\times 2$ matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_2.C3.972_matrices).

Comment: Thanks @GitGud, gosh that one link explains it all. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a Wronskian is a determinant. And the inverse of $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$$ (when it exists) is given by $$A^{-1}={1\over \det A}\begin{bmatrix} d & -b\\ -c & a\end{bmatrix}.$$

Compare this with your $(3)$ and $(4)$.

Comment: Thanks! Man, I need to look this stuff up. In many ways, matrices seem to organize things so much better. They don't seem to be very difficult either, just a matter of memorizing all of the rules like differentiation etc. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Glad to help. The more you learn/farther you go in mathematics you will see more and more connections between all the things you've already done.